# ChemicalData[] error: "L-Cysteine" is not a known entity, class,

Tags: curated-data, chemistry

If I execute:

```
ChemicalData["L-Cysteine", "MolarMass"]
```

I get the following error:

> ChemicalData::notent: "L-Cysteine" is not a known entity, class, or tag for ChemicalData. Use ChemicalData[] for a list of entities.

However

```
ChemicalData["L-Alanine", "MolarMass"]
```

works fine.

Is this a bug? How can I retrieve the molar mass of L-Cysteine?

Comment: Use a wildcard character: `ChemicalData["L*Cysteine"]`

Comment: That is most unusual.  `ChemicalData["LCysteine", #] & /@ {"Name", "StandardName", 
  "FormattedName"}` gives `{"L-cysteine", "LCysteine", "L-cysteine"}` but `ChemicalData["L-cysteine", "MolarMass"]` __also does not work__. (It tells me that L-cysteine is not a known entity).  In addition, the three letter codes (Ala, for example) work with Wolfram Alpha, but do not work with _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to try to figure such things out is to use [Free-Form Input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html).

Type a '=', type a phrase, and execute.  You'll get an output cell, which you can click to turn into input cell.  Then `InputForm` will often show you what you're looking for.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can see that, just as @becko has already found out, that the *Mathematica* name for L-cysteine is `"LCysteine"`.

Comment: I think Ctrl-= is a better tool for this, as the output is the desired entity.

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out:

```
ChemicalData["LCysteine", "MolarMass"]
```

Turns out `ChemicalData["LAlanine", "MolarMass"]` also works. It seems that `ChemicalData["L-Alanine", "MolarMass"]` with the dash is a notational exception allowed only with alanine.

Comment: It seems to me that the "Name" and "FormattedName" used by _Mathematica_ for the amino acids are of the form L-lowercase-name. `ChemicalData["L-Alanine", #] & /@ {"Name", "StandardName", 
  "FormattedName", "IUPACName", "AlternateNames", "CASNumber"}` gives `{"L-alanine", "LAlanine", "L-alanine", "(2S)-2-aminopropanoic acid", \
{"(2S)-2-aminopropionic acid"}, "CAS56-41-7"}`.  But the inconsistencies are frustrating, to say the least.